# copiar y pegar con cmd desde python

Tags: python, ssh

Que tal estoy intentando copiar y pegar archivos desde una cmd de windows usando python
tengo el siguiente codigo

```
import subprocess
import paramiko

from datetime import datetime

fecha = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    comando = "cd Downloads && md "+fecha
    comando3 = "copy C:/Users/pcssh/Desktop/prueba/*.* C:/Users/pcssh/Desktop/prueba2"
    comando2 = "xcopy /E /I /C C:/Users/pcssh/Desktop/prueba/ C:/Users/pcssh/Desktop/prueba2"
    def ssh2(ip,username,passwd,comando,comando2):
        try:
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(ip,22,username,passwd,timeout=5)
    
    
            stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(comando)
            #stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(comando3)
    
    
            #f = open("C:/Users/yo/Desktop/prueba/pruebatxt.txt", "r")
            #for linea in f:
            #    stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(linea)
            #    print(linea)
    
    
            #print(stdout.read())
    
            print('%s OK\n'%(ip))
            ssh.close()
        except :
            print('%s Error\n' %(ip))
     
    ssh2("DireccionIP","Usuario","Pass",comando,comando2)
```

ya intente con el metodo de comando2 y con comando3 y no funciona la accion de copiar y pegar solo  funciona el primer comando

```
comando = "cd Downloads && md "+fecha
```

presiento que el error esta en como pongo la ruta pero ya intente con doble barra `//` y con barra invertida `\\` y no ejecuta ese comando

Comment: Algún mensaje de error al correr esas instrucciones?

Comment: No dice que se ejecuta correctamente pero no hace nada

Comment: Yo tengo un script parecido solo que completamente de Python copia los archivos solo que no se muestran hasta que actualizo el Escritorio haz esto: Escritorio>Click derecho> Actualizar

Answer (score 0):

hay varias formas de hacer esto pero la que yo uso es:

```
cmd_1 = 'comando de prueba'
cmd_2 = 'comando de prueba'
# ( ; para windows ) ( && para linux )
comando = f'{cmd_1} ; {cmd_2}'
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(comando)
```

Esta es el mas sencillo a mi parecer.

Comment: Disculpa me podrias explicar por que y como funciona la sintaxis f'{cmd_1} ya que intuyo que lel primer comando si me lo ejecuta, comando2 y comnado3 no esas son mis opciones de copia y pega presiento que es por las barras `/` al momento de pasarle una ruta  `C:/Users/pcssh/Desktop/prueba/`

Comment: son simples variables que las unes en un una gran variable que es "comando", el f'{variable}' sirve para concatenar variables, el equivalente seria comando = cmd_1 + ' ; ' + cmd_2 . cuantos mas comandos mas cmd_etc o commando1,2,3,4 etc es un ejemplo lo que te pase.

Comment: La idea de esto es concatenar los comandos que pasas en los parametros de la funcion y generar un solo comando anidado con ;  Asi te funcionara con un solo exec. y no tendras que cerrar ese exec por completo y generar otro. es el metodo mas sencillo.